# How to add automatically Number in Column D base on the Column E options

Tags: excel

I am trying to add the serial number automatically according to column E. I am using `=Row()`
formula but it is not working as wanted. The sheets looks like this.

[image]

The data given in column E is just sample data. It may be any test. Like "1- What is your name?", "What is your qualification?" Etc. The `=Right()` function would not work on it because the data will be text only.

Here is updated example

[image]

Comment: Can you post a different data sample? You said *The =Right() function would not work* but looking at your image it's your best option indeed.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns, brother, I have updated the post please check.

Comment: @ShakeelAhmadMscit Give a try to my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below formula.

```
=IF(C3<>"",1,D2+1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula: =IF(E3="","",MAX($D$3:D3)+1)

Comment: it is generating series of the number but I need different for each category. Please see my attachment.

Comment: I cannot able to open your attachment. How many categories you have? and specify what do you want to add based on your category and used the if function with multiple criteria on it.